# Python problem in Linux

Tags: python

Whenever I run a .py exploit I run into a lot of problems. Please see this & tell what shoould I do?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exploit.py", line 177, in <module>
    dump_salt()
  File "exploit.py", line 87, in dump_salt
    r = session.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 184, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 156, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

Please help me. I cannot fix it ;(
Should I reinstall python3 then how ?

Comment: There should be more output before or after the traceback that hints at the problem. Please include everything, as well as what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: If possible, can you please share your .py file?
Also, kindly confirm if you're using the correct runtime (3.x or 2.7) for your script.
On face of it, this problem seems to be somewhere from network/socket/port. Please confirm if your script is having access to the required ports (of if ports are free), having necessary privileged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sock.connect(sa)
```

Probably something can't connect somewhere. Therefore, I'm sure reinstalling Python won't help :) However, if you check where should it connect to and why it can't. Good pointer should be what's written before the traceback.

Comment: Ah, Thank you, you saved my day ! The URL I was typed was missing a directory.